# PYCUDA setting NVCC arguments

Tags: python, pycuda

if i have any small pycuda code such as the one below, how can i access options of the nvcc compiler? for example if i want to set -maxrregcount 20 (or any other argument), how would i accomplish that>

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy

from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""")

multiply_them = mod.get_function("multiply_them")

a = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)
b = numpy.random.randn(400).astype(numpy.float32)

dest = numpy.zeros_like(a)
multiply_them(
        drv.Out(dest), drv.In(a), drv.In(b),
        block=(400,1,1), grid=(1,1))

print dest-a*b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well i found that the answer is rather simple all we need to do is add the code below..

```
mod = SourceModule("""
__global__ void multiply_them(float *dest, float *a, float *b)
{
  const int i = threadIdx.x;
  dest[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}
""",options=['--maxrregcount=20'])
```